# Change logo location in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

How to change logo location in Magento CE 2.0.2 ?

I want to move logo to `header.panel` block.

Tried to do it through layout/xml but that only provides changing position (before/after).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this approach to move a block:

```
   <move element="logo" destination="header.panel" />
```

with attributes "**before**" or "**after**".

You can use "before" = "-" to place your element at the very begin of the destination and  "after" = "-" to place your element at the very end of the destination. 
Look at [the source code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/layout/admin_login.xml) for examples.

You can find also another approach. This one is about using [actions "unsetChild" and "insert"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410206/change-order-of-blocks-via-local-xml-file-in-magento).